# POST http://localhost:4200/ 404 Not found (Request from Angular to Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, rest

I want to know what I am doing here:

What is the meaning of the error that I am getting here? What does it indicate? What is the way to solve this?

[image]

`app.js` from `node.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");

var corsOptions = {
};

var routesApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

require('./app_api/models/db')

var routesApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');

app.use('/api', routesApi)
app.use('/hello', routesApi)
app.use('/', routesApi)

module.exports = app;
```

**app_api/routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var router  = express.Router()

var ctrlLocations = require('../controllers/locations')
var ctrlReviews   = require('../controllers/reviews')

router.post('/', ctrlLocations.helloCreate);

module.exports = router
```

**hello-service.service.ts** from Angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4200';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HelloServiceService 
{
  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  create( data: {} ) 
  {
    console.log("data:", data)
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }

}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be running on port 4200 to receive a post to /? That's the default port for the Angular dev server, have you moved that to a different port or added a proxy? What port is the express app running on? Have you tried making the same request from a different client (curl, postman, ...) to see if the problem is in the frontend or backend?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for asking these questions. These questions will help to find what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First looks like you are missing a statement in your nodejs app that specifies the port to listen to. Something like:

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Second you don't want to send a POST request to `http://localhost:4200` because it is your frontend angular app and does not support POST request, which is why you are getting 404. You want to send request to your node app rather which in the example above will be `http://localhost:3000`.
Try that.